# Displaying list in new activity through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need to pass a list from one activity to another. I have used intent and passed it to next activity and got it verified. If it is a string then the passed intent value can be set to a textView. But as it is a list I do not know to display it on the second activity.  Whether should i pass the list to a textView or listView or how else can I do?? Kindly help with syntax.

Comment: if you need to show *text*, you need a `TextView`. If you need to display a *list*, you need a what?

Comment: Search for 'Android how to pass list in Activity' on Google.

Comment: ListView? But i do not how how to set the list to it.

Comment: First for transfer list from one activity to another activity try to use SingleTon class. And in second activity use ListViewAdapter to display list data row wise.

Comment: `But i do not how how to set the list to it` then you should find some example, it's easy to use google, trust me. There are already few thousands of examples.

Comment: Thisis a very-basic task for android. Since you don't know how to do it, then you didn't pass a basic training lessons for android. Please do that before continuing, or you'll get a tone of such questions.

Comment: As it is a very basic task can you provide the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You must use recycler view to implement your requirement

Refer: https: www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Kindly consider adding essential parts of the answer here because the link can become invalid in future but info. here shall still benefit future users.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass a List with a intent?

1. The javaBean in the List you want to passed , need to implement the serializable interface.
2. You also need to  convert the list to the serializable compulsively and put it in a intent ,such as

   ```
           Intent intentPut = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentTestActivity.class);  
           intentPut.putExtra("lstBean", (Serializable) lstBean);  
           startActivity(intentPut);
   ```
3. Then you can get the List on the target Activity.

   List lstBean = (List) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lstBean");

Comment: iam able to pass the list but not able to display it

Comment: So your question is , **you don't know how to display a list with ListView or RecyclerView**? @RasigaVarun

Comment: It is very basic for Android.  It is a simmple demo.  http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

Comment: And I think that you should strengthen your knowledge for Android.